# How to copy files from a list without extension to a different folder?

Tags: bash, shell-script, filenames, wildcards, cp

I have a text file that contains a list of ids of files without any extension now I need to copy those files mentioned in the list

```
head 01cBC.txt
EE87786
EE87787
EE87788
EE87789
EE87790
EE87791
```

Now, I have multiple files with the same ids which (e.g. EE87786.L.csv, EE87786.R.csv, EE87786.N.csv) which I need to copy into a different folder. So, How can I do it!

So far what I did:

```
mkdir 01cBC

while read file;
do
  temp="${file%\"}"
  temp="${temp#\"}"
  cp "CNcsv/$temp" "CNcsv/01cBC"
done < 01cBC.txt
```

Error Output:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘CNcsv/EE87786’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘CNcsv/EE87787’: No such file or directory
```

Therefore, this is a sincere request please suggest me the best way to proceed.

Thanks,
Deb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got the solution,

```
for file in $(<01cBC.txt); 
    do 
    cp "$file".* 01cBC; 
    done;
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't use for loop to read a file, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001